# PHP - Having more than one htmlentities() in your code

Tags: php, html-entities, html-injections

I just came across building a **CRUD** application in **PHP**, and the instructor was reminding us about the use of **htmlentities()** in order to avoid **HTML injections**, and he then goes to say that **htmlentities** shouldnt be called more than once in your code, my question is very simple...why?

Cheers

Comment: Not sure their reasoning, but my guess is if you use it multiple times in a row, you'll end up with multiple levels of encodings https://3v4l.org/GkDmb

Comment: You can still try using escape functions instead of "htmlentities": D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because calling it a second time on the same value can double-encode it.

Taking the example from the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

$firstEntity = htmlentities($str);
// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
```

Now if we run that through `htmlentities()` again it will encode the ampersands that the first `htmlentities()` call created and you'll end up with a double-encoded string:

```
$secondEntity = htmlentities($firstEntity);
// Outputs: A 'quote' is &amp;lt;b&amp;gt;bold&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;
```

Comment: Of course, makes total sense, cheers brother.

Comment: While this is technically correct, `HTMLentities` [does have a flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to prevent double encoding so to answer the question, there's no reason not to double run this function on the same string, however it would be a pointless waste of time and resources.

Answer (score 1):

There are two important things to know about escaping:

- You should not run *the same escape function twice on the same value*. For instance `htmlentities('1 > 2')` will give you `1 &gt; 2`, but `htmlentities(htmlentities('1 > 2'))` will give you `1 &amp;gt; 2`.
- You should only run escape functions *at the point you're sending the data somewhere*. In the case of HTML escaping, you should do it *as you're sending to the browser*, not when you save to the database, or when you're combining different strings somewhere in your application. If you don't, you don't actually know the right escape function to use, and are likely to end up with corrupted data, or even introducing new vulnerabilities.

Saying "only do it one place" is a way of remembering *both* of these things: if you *only* do it *immediately as you output it*, you won't accidentally double-escape the same string, and you won't apply the wrong escaping for a string you're going to use somewhere else.